The name is Blank, when it is set any name to ".SeriesCollection(1).Name"
I am written the below source to change the series of graph in Excel VBA (Excel version: 2404 build: 17531.20152 quick execution)
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1). Chart

.SeriesCollection(1). XValues = Range(Cells (11, 1, Cells (2000, 1)) 'x-axis : time

.SeriesCollection(1). Name = Range(Cells (10, 2), Cells (10, 2)) 'series name

.SeriesCollection(1). Values = Range(Cells (11, 2), Cells (2000, 2)) 'y-axis : data

End With

I carried this out, but the series name became the blank on graph.
I am tried the below 2 cases, but the result is same (Blank)
case 1
.SeriesCollection(1). Name = Range(Cells (10, 2)) 'series name

case 2
.SeriesCollection(1). Name = Range("J10") 'series name

In addition, I was a comment ('.SeriesCollection(1). Name) and type series name on graph.
I carried a codes of VBA, series name is BLANK.
Please give me a advice.

Range(Cells (10, 2)) will only work if B10 contains a valid range address.  Otherwise, that code works OK for me.

Your code seems to work fine to me, if the graph name is blank maybe you should check "Range" assignation or use "Text" property instead of default property "Value"
Sub GraphName()
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
'        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range(Cells(10, 2), Cells(10, 2))    'series name B10
'        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Cells(10, 2)    'series name B10
'        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("B10")    'series name B10
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Range("B10").Text    'series name B10
    End With
End Sub

